# MySQL mobilink synchronization with SQL Anywhere

Tags: mysql, sqlanywhere, mobilink

My computer configurations are

- MySQL-mysql-5.0.96
- SQL Anywhere-11
- win XP 32 bit

I am trying to connect mysql with sql anywhere for mobilink syncronization but getting error while following the tutorial given at this site: http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1056497 at step [Starting the MobiLink Synchronization Server](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1056497#startmlsrv)

```
start "" "%SQLANY11%\bin32\mlsrv11" -v+ -o mlsrv.out -zs ml_mysql -c "DSN=sa11_ML" -dl -zu+ -x tcpip{port=2439}
```

error which I'm getting:

> [-10002]Consolidated database server or ODBC error: ODBC:[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysql-5.0.24a-community-nt]Incorrect datetime value:'2134-09-08 07:06:05.100000000' for column 'last_modified' at row 1 (ODBC State = HY000, Native error code = 1292)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out the solution for the above asked question by me.

Use the following versions

MySQL - 5.5
MySQL ODBC - 5.1 
 instead of above given.

and try to use the steps by executing bat file provided.